# How to access the previous clipboard in VBA Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word, clipboard

I am writing macro where I need to paste clipboard into MS Word. When I have run my code it happens error 4605 and debugger stops on line #11.

```
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Documents.Add.Content.Paste
If False Then
ErrHandler:
  ' Add a delay
  Dim tmpStart
  tmpStart = Timer
  Do
    DoEvents
  Loop While (tmpStart + 1) > Timer
  Documents.Add.Content.Paste
End If
```

When I check the clipboard panel in MS Word I see this:

[image]

The last item caused problem. But what I need to access is the item marked in red rectangle. So in the case that the error happens I need to get the previous clipboard in the Word's Memory. Can you tell me how to achieve it?

**Edit:**

So far I have found [this question](http://visualbasic.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/vb-vba-l/select-a-clipboard-item-vba-5363109), which is concerned about the problem.